# A person who place an order

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

An order is placed by one and taken by another. It seems appreciate to call a person who takes an order a "order taker", but I don't know how to refer to the one who place an order.

Possible choices:

- order placer
- order submitter
- order putter

Either a word or a phrase is OK.

Comment: Related: [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289281/orderer-person-who-orders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the word **orderer** is ok, if you really need that. But it's not very common.

Now in what situation? In a restaurant, you'd really just say "customer" or "patron". For some kind of supplies company, over the phone, I'd say "customer".

The most natural thing, if you must use the word "order", is "**person who placed the order**". That's what I would say.

Answer (score 0):

'order-giver' is a valid and not too uncommon construct, and is quite general.  (33million google results, compared  with 539k results for orderer)

It does have a connotation of someone who has the authority to give orders, whereas, e.g. a customer in a restaurant is generally making more of a request, and has no formal authority over the person receiving the order.

Generally, a phrase such as the 'person who places the order' is more usual.

Answer (score -1):

As my previous answer was deemed unsuitable, I’ll paraphrase it:
For some time now, I have been using “order placer” to translate the Spanish phrase “quién hace el pedido” (person who places the order) into English in software strings.
“Orderer” is another option, but as our colleague notes above, it doesn’t seem to be very widely used. Many people will just say “buyer/customer/client”, but the person or entity purchasing the commodity or service in question may not actually be the person or entity that places the order, which may be done an intermediary or agent of some sort. Hence, sometimes it is necessary to specify exactly who placed the order.

Comment: Hello Acme,  the last "answer" was deleted, and I think this one will be deleted too.    The reason is that you don't answer the question. This largely restates the original question, and the answer to it is in the accepted answer "customer" is normal "person who placed the order" can be used if it is necessary to specify exactly who placed the order.  If you think you can write a better answer, than the accepted accepted answer you can write it.  But this isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: I’m sorry if you think my answer isn’t good enough, or somehow doesn’t respond to the question. However, I disagree and think I have provided a clear explanation of my preferences (citing and agreeing with the asker’s first option), backed by my current practice and experience as a translator.

Comment: I've suggested "Order Placer" and explained why, I really don't see how this"does not provide an answer to the question." The solution I'm proposing is "Order Placer", as it is not always the customer per se who places the order.